# Speed of AC and DC current

Tags: electric-current

If AC current oscillates as it passes through a conductor is it slower than DC current which does not oscillates?

Comment: What do you mean by "slower"? Are you aware that the AC current *changes its direction* when it "oscillates", so it can't really have a constant velocity assigned to it?

Comment: The electrons that carry the current are scattering at a rate much faster than AC frequencies - they really don't notice.

Answer (score 1):

> **is [AC current] slower than DC current**

Current doesn't have a speed, it is a measure of charge passing per unit time.

Current can be larger or smaller but not faster or slower.

If we know the Mississippi river flows at a rate of 17000 $m^3s^{-1}$, we don't know how fast the water is moving (and for many purposes may not care).

> **If AC current oscillates**

It does.

The magnitude and direction of the electric field changes and reverses in a sinusiodal pattern. So the force on the charge carriers (e.g. electrons in some cases) will vary and reverse, so the acceleration of the drift velocity of the charge carriers will not be constant.

Electrical/Electronic engineers mostly don't need to know the drift velocity of charge carriers in electrical conductors.

In practice, we measure alternating current in such a way (Root mean square) that we can use the numbers in calculations in much the same way we do for direct current.

---

Related:

- [How fast does an electron travel in a circuit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145309/how-fast-does-an-electron-travel-in-a-circuit)
- [What is the speed of electrical current in salt water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71303/12613)
- [In an alternating current, do electrons flow from the source to the device?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28036/12613)