# Permittivity of an object

Tags: conductors

Is it possible that an object is a conductor and its permittivity is equal to the permittivity of vacuum? Is there any relationship between the permittivity and the conductivity?

Comment: Related: [Relation between permittivity and conductivity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67026/)

Comment: Formally conductivity can be related to the imaginary part of permittivity. Check out the wikipedia item http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity.